# Filter pandas dataframe based on a column: keep all rows if a value is that column

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe like the following:

```
Name    Age    City
A       21     NY
A       20     DC
A       35     OR
B       18     DC
B       19     PA
```

I need to keep all the rows for every `Name` and `Age` pair where a specific value is among those associated with column `City`. For example if my target city is `NY`, then my desired output would be:

```
Name    Age    City
A       21     NY
A       20     DC
A       35     OR
```

**Edit1:** I am not necessarily looking for a single value. There might be cases where there are multiple cities that I am looking for. For example: `NY` and `DC` at the same time.

**Edit2:** I have tried the followings which does not return correct output (daah):

```
df = df[df['City'] == 'NY']
```

and

```
df = df[df['City'].isin('NY')]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create function - first test `City` for equal and get all unique names for again filtering by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
def get_df_by_val(df, val):
    return df[df['Name'].isin(df.loc[df['City'].eq(val), 'Name'].unique())]

print (get_df_by_val(df, 'NY'))
  Name  Age City
0    A   21   NY
1    A   20   DC
2    A   35   OR

print (get_df_by_val(df, 'PA'))
  Name  Age City
3    B   18   DC
4    B   19   PA

print (get_df_by_val(df, 'OR'))
  Name  Age City
0    A   21   NY
1    A   20   DC
2    A   35   OR
```

EDIT:

If need check multiple values per groups use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with compare `set`s with `issubset`:

```
vals = ['NY', 'DC']

df1 = df[df.groupby('Name')['City'].transform(lambda x: set(vals).issubset(x))]
print (df1)
  Name  Age City
0    A   21   NY
1    A   20   DC
2    A   35   OR
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question and wondering what I might need to do in case I am looking for multiple values